# Default function parameter value from React component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, default-parameters

Today I did a review for my colleague and I found a function definition that interested me. He implemented a function inside a react component with default parameter values if the function call is not provided with an argument. He used a `state` value as a default parameter.

It looked like this example:

```
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         this.state = {
             loadedData = [], // array of objects
         };

         this.filterDates = (fromUtc, toUtc, loadedData = this.state.loadedData) {
             // do something with 'loadedData' based on time range 'fromUtc' and 'toUtc'
         }
    }
}
```

He could not provide me a good explanation. Only that it works in his implementation.

I have always used 'static' default parameter values (like `[]`, number, etc.) 
I am curious if it is ok to use some kind of 'dynamic' default parameter, which changes when `state` changes.

Is it ok to write it like this? Could be there a problematic case?

Comment: Should be OK I guess? But why is the argument optional in the first place?

Comment: Where is the logic in that if you can just pass `this.state.loadedData`?

Comment: In my POV, this is bad. default value should be a static value and if there is a dynamic value, it will be based on business logic and should be a part of body instead

Comment: @dennis-vash I am not sure if I understand your question. The logic with passing `this.state.loadedData` is within the component itself, but in different function. Once he filters the array from `state ` calling `filterDates(fromUtc, toUtc)` (without third parameter) and second time there is a call with a different array reference which follow `this.state.loadedData` format. (It might be confusing that the function parameter is called `loadedData`)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Airbnb Javascript Style Guide -es6 default parameters](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es6-default-parameters) this approach is good. However I question assigning default value to state which is mutable by definition unless it's desired effect. Default parameter shouldn't be mutable. Personally I see such approach for the first time and I think it's not intuitive but maybe it's just my experience.

In my opinion code below is cleaner, easier to understand and less buggy:

```js
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         this.state = {
             loadedData = [], // array of objects
         };

         this.filterDates = (fromUtc, toUtc, loadedData = []) => {
             // do something with 'loadedData' based on time range 'fromUtc' and 'toUtc'
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, this.state is a simple object without any magical feature of states. So, `loadedData = this.state.loadedData` is the same as `loadedData = []` but the second one is more readable.